# swift - UICollectionView issue "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, fatal-error

**EDIT:**

After adding exception breakpoint (thanks to Daniel T), I found out that it was my

```
cell.askingUsernameLabel.text = NSString(string: arr[indexPath.row])
```

which was returning nil.

The solution to this problem is that within swift, registering Sub classes overwrite what you did in Storyboards (if using storyboard). Just delete

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CollectionViewCell")
```

and you're good to go

**ORIGINAL**

Im really lost with this one: Im trying to set a UICollectionView inside a UIView from my ViewController. (Storyboard)

I set this up following several tutorial / code examples, but I cant find out why I end always end up with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

here is the code.

Controller hierarchy:

```
View Controller (class:ViewController.swift)
-- UIView 1
-- UIView 2
----- UICollectionView
---------- UICollectionViewCell (class:CollectionViewCell.swift) (dataSource & delegate linked to View Contorller)
--------------- Label
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var arr:[String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arr = ["title1", "title2"]

        self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CollectionViewCell")

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
        cell.askingUsernameLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } 

}
```

CollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var askingUsernameLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong to end up with this fatal error?

```
there`@objc there.ViewController.collectionView (there.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UICollectionViewCell at ViewController.swift:
0xb08c0:  pushl  %ebp
0xb08c1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0xb08c3:  pushl  %esi
0xb08c4:  subl   $0x24, %esp
0xb08c7:  movl   0x14(%ebp), %eax
0xb08ca:  movl   0x10(%ebp), %ecx
0xb08cd:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %edx
0xb08d0:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0xb08d3:  movl   %ecx, -0x8(%ebp)
0xb08d6:  movl   %edx, -0xc(%ebp)
0xb08d9:  movl   %eax, -0x10(%ebp)
0xb08dc:  calll  0x13f0e0                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0xb08e1:  movl   -0x10(%ebp), %ecx
0xb08e4:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0xb08e7:  movl   %eax, -0x14(%ebp)
0xb08ea:  calll  0x13f0e0                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0xb08ef:  movl   -0xc(%ebp), %ecx
0xb08f2:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0xb08f5:  movl   %eax, -0x18(%ebp)
0xb08f8:  calll  0x13f0e0                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0xb08fd:  movl   -0x8(%ebp), %ecx
0xb0900:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0xb0903:  movl   -0x10(%ebp), %edx
0xb0906:  movl   %edx, 0x4(%esp)
0xb090a:  movl   -0xc(%ebp), %esi
0xb090d:  movl   %esi, 0x8(%esp)
0xb0911:  movl   %eax, -0x1c(%ebp)
0xb0914:  calll  0xb0240                   ; there.ViewController.collectionView (there.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UICollectionViewCell at ViewController.swift:124
0xb0919:  movl   %esp, %ecx
0xb091b:  movl   %eax, (%ecx)
0xb091d:  calll  0x13f06e                  ; symbol stub for: objc_autoreleaseReturnValue
0xb0922:  addl   $0x24, %esp
0xb0925:  popl   %esi
0xb0926:  popl   %ebp
0xb0927:  retl   

UIKit`-[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]:
0x2730b98:  pushl  %ebp
0x2730b99:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x2730b9b:  pushl  %ebx
0x2730b9c:  pushl  %edi
0x2730b9d:  pushl  %esi
0x2730b9e:  subl   $0x5c, %esp
0x2730ba1:  calll  0x2730ba6                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 14
0x2730ba6:  popl   %esi
0x2730ba7:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %edi
0x2730baa:  movl   0x6307aa(%esi), %ebx
0x2730bb0:  cmpl   $0x0, (%edi,%ebx)
0x2730bb4:  jne    0x2730c29                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 145
0x2730bb6:  movl   0x6276ba(%esi), %eax
0x2730bbc:  movl   0x611b46(%esi), %ecx
0x2730bc2:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730bc6:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730bc9:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730bce:  movl   %eax, -0x34(%ebp)
0x2730bd1:  movl   0x6276be(%esi), %eax
0x2730bd7:  movl   0x611b4a(%esi), %ecx
0x2730bdd:  leal   0x31216a(%esi), %edx
0x2730be3:  movl   %edx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730be7:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730beb:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730bee:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730bf3:  movl   0x611b4e(%esi), %ecx
0x2730bf9:  leal   0x519532(%esi), %edx
0x2730bff:  movl   %edx, 0x18(%esp)
0x2730c03:  movl   %eax, 0x10(%esp)
0x2730c07:  movl   %edi, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730c0b:  movl   0xc(%ebp), %eax
0x2730c0e:  movl   %eax, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730c12:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730c16:  movl   -0x34(%ebp), %eax
0x2730c19:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730c1c:  movl   $0x51c, 0x14(%esp)
0x2730c24:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730c29:  movl   0x10(%ebp), %edx
0x2730c2c:  movl   0x63075a(%esi), %eax
0x2730c32:  movl   (%edi,%eax), %eax
0x2730c35:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x2730c37:  je     0x2730c7d                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 229
0x2730c39:  movl   0x6307b6(%esi), %ecx
0x2730c3f:  cmpl   $0x1, (%edi,%ecx)
0x2730c43:  jne    0x2730c7d                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 229
0x2730c45:  movl   0x611e16(%esi), %ecx
0x2730c4b:  movl   %edx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730c4f:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730c53:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730c56:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730c5b:  movl   0x10(%ebp), %edx
0x2730c5e:  testb  %al, %al
0x2730c60:  je     0x2730c7d                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 229
0x2730c62:  movl   0x630752(%esi), %eax
0x2730c68:  movl   (%edi,%eax), %eax
0x2730c6b:  movl   0x611a4e(%esi), %ecx
0x2730c71:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730c75:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730c78:  jmp    0x273100d                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 1141
0x2730c7d:  movl   (%edi,%ebx), %eax
0x2730c80:  movl   0x62428a(%esi), %ecx
0x2730c86:  movl   %edx, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730c8a:  movl   %edi, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730c8e:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730c92:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730c95:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730c9a:  movl   %eax, %ebx
0x2730c9c:  testl  %ebx, %ebx
0x2730c9e:  jne    0x2730d19                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 385
0x2730ca0:  movl   0x6276ba(%esi), %eax
0x2730ca6:  movl   0x611b46(%esi), %ecx
0x2730cac:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730cb0:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730cb3:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730cb8:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x2730cba:  movl   0x6276be(%esi), %eax
0x2730cc0:  movl   0x611b4a(%esi), %ecx
0x2730cc6:  leal   0x31216a(%esi), %edx
0x2730ccc:  movl   %edx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730cd0:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730cd4:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730cd7:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730cdc:  movl   0x611b4e(%esi), %ecx
0x2730ce2:  movl   0x10(%ebp), %edx
0x2730ce5:  movl   %edx, 0x1c(%esp)
0x2730ce9:  leal   0x519542(%esi), %edx
0x2730cef:  movl   %edx, 0x18(%esp)
0x2730cf3:  movl   %eax, 0x10(%esp)
0x2730cf7:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
0x2730cfa:  movl   %eax, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730cfe:  movl   0xc(%ebp), %eax
0x2730d01:  movl   %eax, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730d05:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730d09:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x2730d0c:  movl   $0x522, 0x14(%esp)
0x2730d14:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730d19:  movl   0x6154de(%esi), %eax
0x2730d1f:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730d23:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x2730d26:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730d2b:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x2730d2d:  jne    0x2730da1                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 521
0x2730d2f:  movl   0x6276ba(%esi), %eax
0x2730d35:  movl   0x611b46(%esi), %ecx
0x2730d3b:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730d3f:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730d42:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730d47:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x2730d49:  movl   0x6276be(%esi), %eax
0x2730d4f:  movl   0x611b4a(%esi), %ecx
0x2730d55:  leal   0x31216a(%esi), %edx
0x2730d5b:  movl   %edx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730d5f:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730d63:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730d66:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730d6b:  movl   0x611b4e(%esi), %ecx
0x2730d71:  leal   0x519552(%esi), %edx
0x2730d77:  movl   %edx, 0x18(%esp)
0x2730d7b:  movl   %eax, 0x10(%esp)
0x2730d7f:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
0x2730d82:  movl   %eax, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730d86:  movl   0xc(%ebp), %eax
0x2730d89:  movl   %eax, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730d8d:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730d91:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x2730d94:  movl   $0x523, 0x14(%esp)
0x2730d9c:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730da1:  movl   %ebx, %edi
0x2730da3:  movl   0x4d2486(%esi), %eax
0x2730da9:  movl   (%eax), %eax
0x2730dab:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x2730dad:  je     0x273101a                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 1154
0x2730db3:  cmpl   $0x6ffff, %eax
0x2730db8:  seta   %bl
0x2730dbb:  movl   0x62428e(%esi), %eax
0x2730dc1:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730dc5:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x2730dc8:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730dcd:  testb  %bl, %bl
0x2730dcf:  je     0x2730e64                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 716
0x2730dd5:  testb  %al, %al
0x2730dd7:  movl   %edi, %ebx
0x2730dd9:  movl   0x14(%ebp), %ecx
0x2730ddc:  jne    0x2730e8a                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 754
0x2730de2:  movl   0x6276ba(%esi), %eax
0x2730de8:  movl   0x611b46(%esi), %ecx
0x2730dee:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730df2:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730df5:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730dfa:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x2730dfc:  movl   0x6276be(%esi), %eax
0x2730e02:  movl   0x611b4a(%esi), %ecx
0x2730e08:  leal   0x31216a(%esi), %edx
0x2730e0e:  movl   %edx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730e12:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730e16:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730e19:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730e1e:  movl   0x611b4e(%esi), %ecx
0x2730e24:  movl   %ebx, 0x20(%esp)
0x2730e28:  movl   0x10(%ebp), %edx
0x2730e2b:  movl   %edx, 0x1c(%esp)
0x2730e2f:  leal   0x519562(%esi), %edx
0x2730e35:  movl   %edx, 0x18(%esp)
0x2730e39:  movl   %eax, 0x10(%esp)
0x2730e3d:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
0x2730e40:  movl   %eax, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730e44:  movl   0xc(%ebp), %eax
0x2730e47:  movl   %eax, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730e4b:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730e4f:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x2730e52:  movl   $0x524, 0x14(%esp)
0x2730e5a:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730e5f:  movl   0x14(%ebp), %ecx
0x2730e62:  jmp    0x2730e8a                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 754
0x2730e64:  testb  %al, %al
0x2730e66:  movl   %edi, %ebx
0x2730e68:  movl   0x14(%ebp), %ecx
0x2730e6b:  jne    0x2730e8a                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 754
0x2730e6d:  movl   %ebx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730e71:  movl   0x10(%ebp), %eax
0x2730e74:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730e78:  leal   0x519562(%esi), %eax
0x2730e7e:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730e81:  movl   %ecx, %edi
0x2730e83:  calll  0x29148fa                 ; symbol stub for: NSLog
0x2730e88:  movl   %edi, %ecx
0x2730e8a:  movl   %ebx, -0x34(%ebp)
0x2730e8d:  movl   0x624292(%esi), %eax
0x2730e93:  movl   %ecx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730e97:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730e9b:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x2730e9e:  movl   %ecx, %edi
0x2730ea0:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730ea5:  movl   %eax, %ebx
0x2730ea7:  movl   0x611e16(%esi), %eax
0x2730ead:  movl   %edi, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730eb1:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730eb5:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x2730eb8:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730ebd:  testb  %al, %al
0x2730ebf:  jne    0x2730f29                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 913
0x2730ec1:  movl   0x63072e(%esi), %ecx
0x2730ec7:  movl   %ecx, -0x38(%ebp)
0x2730eca:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
0x2730ecd:  movl   (%eax,%ecx), %eax
0x2730ed0:  movl   0x61dfba(%esi), %ecx
0x2730ed6:  movl   %edi, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730eda:  movl   %ebx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730ede:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730ee2:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730ee5:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730eea:  testb  %al, %al
0x2730eec:  je     0x2730f29                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 913
0x2730eee:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
0x2730ef1:  movl   -0x38(%ebp), %ecx
0x2730ef4:  movl   (%eax,%ecx), %ecx
0x2730ef7:  movl   0x61e006(%esi), %eax
0x2730efd:  movl   %edi, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730f01:  movl   %ebx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730f05:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730f09:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0x2730f0c:  movl   %ecx, %ebx
0x2730f0e:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730f13:  movl   0x61dfe2(%esi), %ecx
0x2730f19:  movl   %eax, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730f1d:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730f21:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x2730f24:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730f29:  movl   %edi, %edx
0x2730f2b:  cmpb   $0x0, 0x18(%ebp)
0x2730f2f:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %edi
0x2730f32:  movl   -0x34(%ebp), %ebx
0x2730f35:  je     0x2730f88                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 1008
0x2730f37:  movl   0x6276d2(%esi), %eax
0x2730f3d:  movl   0x4d246e(%esi), %ecx
0x2730f43:  movl   %ecx, -0x30(%ebp)
0x2730f46:  movl   $0xc2000000, -0x2c(%ebp)
0x2730f4d:  movl   $0x0, -0x28(%ebp)
0x2730f54:  leal   0x487(%esi), %ecx
0x2730f5a:  movl   %ecx, -0x24(%ebp)
0x2730f5d:  leal   0x4f864a(%esi), %ecx
0x2730f63:  movl   %ecx, -0x20(%ebp)
0x2730f66:  movl   %edi, -0x1c(%ebp)
0x2730f69:  movl   %edx, -0x18(%ebp)
0x2730f6c:  movl   %ebx, -0x14(%ebp)
0x2730f6f:  movl   0x612d42(%esi), %ecx
0x2730f75:  leal   -0x30(%ebp), %edx
0x2730f78:  movl   %edx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730f7c:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730f80:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730f83:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730f88:  movl   0x62424a(%esi), %eax
0x2730f8e:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730f92:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x2730f95:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730f9a:  movl   0x624272(%esi), %ecx
0x2730fa0:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730fa4:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730fa7:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730fac:  movl   0x62429a(%esi), %ecx
0x2730fb2:  movl   %eax, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730fb6:  movl   %ebx, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730fba:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730fbe:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x2730fc1:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2730fc6:  movl   0x630732(%esi), %eax
0x2730fcc:  movl   (%edi,%eax), %eax
0x2730fcf:  testb  $0x1, %ah
0x2730fd2:  je     0x2731000                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 1128
0x2730fd4:  movl   0x4d277e(%esi), %eax
0x2730fda:  movl   (%eax), %eax
0x2730fdc:  movl   (%edi,%eax), %eax
0x2730fdf:  movl   0x6241ee(%esi), %ecx
0x2730fe5:  movl   0x10(%ebp), %edx
0x2730fe8:  movl   %edx, 0x10(%esp)
0x2730fec:  movl   %ebx, 0xc(%esp)
0x2730ff0:  movl   %edi, 0x8(%esp)
0x2730ff4:  movl   %ecx, 0x4(%esp)
0x2730ff8:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2730ffb:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2731000:  movl   0x611a4e(%esi), %eax
0x2731006:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x273100a:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x273100d:  calll  0x2914ab6                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x2731012:  addl   $0x5c, %esp
0x2731015:  popl   %esi
0x2731016:  popl   %edi
0x2731017:  popl   %ebx
0x2731018:  popl   %ebp
0x2731019:  retl   
0x273101a:  movl   $0x70000, (%esp)
0x2731021:  calll  0x2017c4b                 ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnOrAfter
0x2731026:  movb   %al, %bl
0x2731028:  jmp    0x2730dbb                 ; -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 547
```

Comment: That's not a stack trace, that's a dump of the code near where the exception happened.  The stack trace should be much much shorter.

Comment: I don't know where it is. The black box outputs only the above message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)"

thread1: EX_BAD_INSTRUCTION {code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some breakpoints in your code. Step through each of your functions and look at the values contained by the variables. Find the variable that is nil when it isn't supposed to be.

If the error actually is in the code you presented, then the error is likely in the `cell.askingUsernameLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]` line or the `self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CollectionViewCell")` line.

Do you know how to put in an exception breakpoint? Here's how:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately I don't. Im new to xcode so I must say I still have plenty to learn...

Comment: There you go. Also, Google "Xcode exception breakpoint". I keep an exception breakpoint always on in my code.

Comment: I added an exception breakpoint but it doesn't change anything. At run time it highlights the same line cell.askingUsernameLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]

Comment: Why didn't you mention before that this line was getting highlighted!? Now, which one of the variables are unexpectedly nil? `cell`, `askingUsernameLabel`, `text` or `arr`? Based on the code you posted, I bet `askingUsernameLabel` is nil.

Comment: a popup on return cell says : (UILabel!) askingUsernameLabel = nil
but why? im passing cell.askingUsernameLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]

Comment: There you go. Your code didn't expect `askingUsernameLabel` to be nil, but it is. Congratulations, you found your bug!

Comment: ok but.. why is it nil? I created arr[String] = [], then I passed in some value arr = ["title1", "title2"]. and then I pass the value to cell.askingUsernameLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row] so I don't understand why it's nil..

Comment: That's a different question. Mark this answer and correct and start a new stack overflow question for your new question, and we will help.

Comment: Found my solution... it help when you know what you're looking for. Many thanks for teaching! I updated my question with answer.